# How to make a round map ? using google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Hey guys i am new to creating maps using google maps , I have created a simple map demo **[HERE](http://codeandcode.co/demo/map-demo/)** , the HTML code is below:

HTML:

```
<section class="hox-map" id="hox-map">
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.hox-map {
    height: 400px;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I have used mplace.js plugin and the JS code looks like below:

```
marker = new Maplace({
    locations: [{
        lat: '25.217665',
        lon: '55.2610000',
        zoom: 18,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    }],
    controls_on_map: false,
    map_div: '#hox-map',

    map_options: {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scrollwheel: false
    },

    styles: {
        'Night': [{
            "featureType": "landscape",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#e2e2e2"
            }, {
                "lightness": 20
            }]
        }]
    },
    generate_controls: false,
    controls_on_map: false,
    listeners: {
        click: function(map, event) {
            // console.log('fired');
            // map.setOptions({scrollwheel: true});
        }
    }


}).Load();
```

Now how do i make a round map like below:

[image: round map]

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add border-radius: 50% to element with class canvas_map

Answer (score 0):

`border-radius: 50%` for .canvas_map works

```
 .canvas_map {
   border-radius: 50%;
   -moz-border-radius: 50%;
   -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 }
```

Take a look here. It works fine: [Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/sbtenk31/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try to this css

```
.hox-map {
height: 400px;
width: 400px;
border: solid 2px red;
border-radius: 200px;
z-index: 1;}
```

If it works, you may change the dimensions.

Answer (score -1):

```
.hox-map {
   height: 400px;
   width: 400px;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Can you add parent element on `.hox-map` and then apply these styles on it?

Answer (score -2):

This is another way that you can also make a google map:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Google Map</h1>

<div id="map" style="width:1300px;height:500px;background:yellow"></div>

<script>
function myMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.7631, -85.6206),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=myMap"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is about making a round map, not making a new google map